# I am trying to pass an value from one activity to another activity in android xamrin program

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin

I am trying to pass an value from one activity to another activity in android xamrin program

```
              string name1 = edit.Text.ToString ();
              Intent intent = new Intent(this,typeof(Activity2));
              intent.PutExtra("namepass",name1);
              StartActivity(intent);
```

In second activity I am receiving through get string extra

```
String name = Intent.GetStringExtra ("namepass") ?? "Data Not avaliable";
```

but name1 is showing as unknown identifier

Comment: Not getting your question

Answer (score 0):

How are you retrieving the value in the activity? This is how you should do it:

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("namepass")
```

Comment: in xamrin android i cant find the function getIntent();

Comment: Inside the Activity you can't call getIntent()?